# Magento 2 password reset, admin access failure

Tags: php, magento2

When I try to login to my magento2 site with the admin URL I get the error "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled." I don't know how I forgot the password. I tried to give forgot password and the link was emailed to me but still, I am not able to login to the admin panel even with the newly reset password. I tried to query in the database with this query `UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxNewpassword', 256), ':xxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';` but still no use the same error message continued.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new admin user using magento2 command line tool and login into admin panel using new user and edit the old admin user!

command to create a new admin from command line:

```
 <path_to_magento>/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --    admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

or execute this query:

```
LOCK TABLES `admin_role` WRITE , `admin_user` WRITE;

SET @SALT = "rp";
SET @PASS = CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT( @SALT , "password") ), CONCAT(":", @SALT ));
SELECT @EXTRA := MAX(extra) FROM admin_user WHERE extra IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO `admin_user` (firstname,lastname,email,username,password,created,lognum,reload_acl_flag,is_active,extra,rp_token_created_at) 
VALUES ('Firstname','Lastname','email@example.com','myuser',@PASS,NOW(),0,0,1,@EXTRA,NOW());

INSERT INTO `admin_role` (parent_id,tree_level,sort_order,role_type,user_id,role_name) 
VALUES (1,2,0,'U',(SELECT user_id FROM admin_user WHERE username = 'myuser'),'Firstname');

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: hi thank u for your quick reply. Since i am new to magento i don't know how to write the command and where to write. Could you please guide me to do that .... Thanks in advance

Comment: did you install magento in your computer or its hosted online?

Comment: its hosted online. i have the cpanel

Comment: can you access your server using SSH?

Comment: i am sorry i don't know how to do that.

Comment: check the answer again I added a query for you, this query will add a new user

Comment: but where should i write that. Sorry for asking

Comment: this is SQL query, from your Cpanel access your database and execute it as you tried to perform the update statement in your question.

Comment: thank you so much for your patience in replying to my questions. i got it work

Comment: how you got it work? if by the answer please mark the answer as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need create new user or execute the query.
Go to your Magento root folder via SSH and run below command :

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock ADMINUSERNAME
```

Please Note : ADMINUSERNAME replace with tou admin name 
like : php bin/magento admin:user:unlock admin

Answer (score 0):

Unlock the user first with the following command. Change the "ADMIN USERNAME" with yours.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock ADMINUSERNAME
```

If it doesn't help the above, create the new user with the following command.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create
```

And then it will ask for type the username, password, first name, last name, email id.

Once done above, clear the cache.